# I wrote a simple program in Dev c++ and my problem is that it terminate instantly without even taking an input:((

Tags: terminal, dev-c++, windows-terminal

#include 
using namespace std;

int main(){

```
int n;
cout<<"Enter a number: ";
cin>> n;
cout<<"The number is: " << n;
return 0;
```

}

I tried uninstalling it and install it again but it just keeps doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getch()` before `return 0`. You need to do `include <conio.h>` to be able to use it.

Comment: It still doesn't work:((